# Deleting verticies via geonodes problem

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to delete specific (marked) verticies via geonodes

[image: pic]

However this node setup deletes almost all of geometry. What am I doing wrong? I used similar setup to delete non manifold edges and it worked fine

[image: pic2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a boolean node to compare integers. The boolean compare node converts integers to bools, which are always true except 0.

Instead, use math node in compare mode:

[image]

I suppose, correct setup should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man
I realised that boolean comparsion is a mistake right after I posted this haha